# Android WebView App Crashing

Tags: android, webview

I recently make a WebView App for my website and i have a few versions of it but i like this the best.
On the tutorial guy video, it all works 100% Great but on mine tho, theres tons and tons of errors that i had resoved.
Now one left, the app crashes every single time i tried to start it.
It will show for 2 seconds and then closed.

Here's the stack trace :

```
08-21 20:32:52.060 3149-3149/app.gonenjoy.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: app.gonenjoy.com, PID: 3149
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at app.gonenjoy.com.MainActivity$MyWebviewClient.onPageFinished(MainActivity.java:160)
                  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:449)
                  at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient$AwWebContentsObserver$1.run(AwContentsClient.java:73)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is apriciated.

Tested on Bluestacks & Samsung galaxy young 2
Android Studio v2.3

Comment: share your code

Comment: please share in line 160 of MainActivity.

Comment: @AdnanAli , The code is:
Line 158-163 :        
[AT]Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.dismiss();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }

Comment: @slymnozdmrc , The code is:
Line 158-163 :        [AT]Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.dismiss();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }

Comment: Could you please try below answer than let me know ? I dont know rest of your code because of this I help you limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think inside of super.onPageFinished view is not same of Webview view. See the following working code.I mean it should be mWebview.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   @Override  
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);

   }  

   @Override
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

   }
   });
   mWebView.loadUrl("your url");
```

Comment: After overwriting my exsisting code with yours, it gave me a lot of error.
Can you gave me like the a clearer view?
or did you have any exsisting WebView app that has fixed back button and link is opened on the same URL but external ones open on chrome?

Comment: What kind of error did you receive? Actually I dont understand what you want? Do you want back button and click it return previous page ? Or you have webview and it has a link than click this link open in webview if it is external than open it in chrome ?

Comment: Hello, i had fixed the problem now it is completely fine now...
Now im making a flight booking app.
Thanks for your help, reaally apriciated it

Comment: Thats good have nice coding :)